# PaintCode button press in view using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, paintcode

So I used PaintCode to make a popup view. I used two canvases for it, the main one for the popup and another for a x close button. I want to be able to detect when that x is tapped so I can close the view. The paint code files are a class of type NSObject and I am using another UIView class to call the function. The x button is implemented as follows:

```
//// Symbol Drawing
CGRect symbolRect = CGRectMake(194, 12, 17, 17);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClipToRect(context, symbolRect);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, symbolRect.origin.x, symbolRect.origin.y);

[PinView drawCanvas2WithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, symbolRect.size.width, symbolRect.size.height) resizing: PinViewResizingBehaviorStretch];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use touchesBegan method to detect touch and find if the touch is within the x area or not!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri is that in the NSObject or the UIView or the parent viewcontroller? Thanks